# How to pick the AWS Organizational Account for my VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to setting up AWS environments.

I have an AWS Organization, a Production Account, and the new "Laboratory" account I just created.  I want to create a VPC inside that new Account.

But when I follow the process of setting up the VPC there's no prompt asking "Which Account do you want this VPC to be in?"

Am I misunderstanding some basic AWS concept?  My user has access to both Accounts, so either:

a. I'm already "in" one Account or the other, and my new VPC will be created there...but I see no indicator which I'm in, nor a way to change the current Account.

b. I ought to be able to *pick* the Account when defining the new VPC...but there's no option for this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. I'm already "in" one Account or the other, and my new VPC will be created there...but I see no indicator which I'm in, nor a way to change the current Account.

Yes, when you authenticate, you use the credentials for one of the accounts. You can also check what account you are in with the [aws cli get-caller-identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html):

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

All the resources you create will be in the account where you are authenticated, unless you specificly has setup cross-account and assumed a role in another account.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas - so there's a hard connection between my *user* account and the *Org* Account?  This would make sense but I've not seen it said outright.  If I want a colleague to join me in setting up the Lab, does he need to create a second AWS account associated with the new Lab Org Account?

Comment: @TomK you need to create IAM credentials for your colleague in the lab account, which they will use to login to the lab account.

Comment: Mark B -- thanks.  So I think I phrased that question in a clumsy way (because the word "account" gets blurry in this context).  I should have asked, "Do I need to create a second set of *login credentials* for my colleague, that will let him log into the Lab Account?" -- and your answer is, yes.

Am I on the right track?  If so, I think I have what I need.